# What's the best way to get the full url to a resource in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using as_json in a Rails model to customise the returned json accessed from the controller, like so:

```
def as_json(options={})
    {
      :id         => self.uuid,
      :href       => full_url_to_resource,
      :file       => self.file.url,
      :filename   => self.filename,
      :file_size  => self.file_size,
      :date       => self.created_at
    }
  end
```

I want to provide the full url of the resource to the client as the href attribute. I'm wondering if there is a non-hardcoded way to do this.

I've include the Url Helpers in my model

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Which allows me to do this:

```
:href => url_for_file(:host => "example.com") + '/files/' + self.uuid,
```

That works fine, but I obviously don't want to hardcode the url. Is there a built in way to do this in Rails based on the current URL being accessed or the url defined in default_url_options?

Or should I create a helper to do this instead?

Comment: Why can't you use the normal routes helpers like files_url/files_path and pass in self? Does that not work? I haven't tried to do that within a model--I'm not convinced a model should know about its URLs.

Comment: I can use that, but it still requires the :host parameter. Yeh I'm thinking that this probably shouldn't be in the model. It seems more logical/cleaner to define the json structure in the model instead of the controller, but maybe I can just move it too the controller.

Comment: Oh, that's the part you meant. Use a configuration parameter, environment parameter, or see if rails already has this somewhere-seems like it would.